# Error running WSGI application in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have researched a lot and found this is a very common question. But the fact is I believe somehow pythonanywhere can not detect my `settings.py` file. Moreover, I have checked with the settings file directory and it is the same path as I have input in the WSGI file. I have also installed the required pip files but still getting the same errors.

```
Error running WSGI application

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'

File "/var/www/ewallet_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 33, in <module>

application = get_wsgi_application()

File "/home/ewallet/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)

File "/home/ewallet/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "/home/ewallet/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

File "/home/ewallet/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
```

Here is the wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/ewallet/E-wallet/ewallet/ewallet/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ewallet.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here is the directory image
[image]

Kindly help me to find the bug here. Thank you

Comment: error is not about of pythonanywhere not able to detect your **settings.py** file error is coming because you forgot to install a package named as **django-widget-tweaks** run this command in your pythonanywhere bash ```pip install django-widget-tweaks ``` and restart your webapp

Comment: Hi, @AnkitTiwari as I mentioned, "I have also installed the required pip files but still getting the same errors." so yes I have installed every pip it required.

Comment: Hello @Toufiqur Rahman than this  may be old error go to the error log and check at the bottom to see latest error

Comment: If the error is same than do check for given package in your pythonanywhere bash by running this command ```pip freeze```

Comment: Thank you for the input bro, but I have tried every possible way and also using pip freeze to check installed pip. It seems weird to me that I have installed everything but still an error. I will re-do everything.

Comment: Make sure that you have installed the module for the version of Python/virtualenv that you are using to run your code. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You just entered path incorrectly. It should  be as following:

```
path = '/home/ewallet/E-wallet/ewallet
```

So, correct version of your wsgi.py is as following:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/ewallet/E-wallet/ewallet/ewallet/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ewallet.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```